# How do I get Twitpic/Twitgoo to sync with Facebook photos?

Tags: web-applications, facebook, twitter

I already import my tweets into Facebook so that they become my Facebook status, but is there a way that I can get my Twitpic/Twitgoo/other Twitter photo services to post photos to my Facebook wall automatically or sync with a Facebook album?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shozu and PixelPipe are two services that allow you to upload to multiple destinations at once. There's no sync really involved but it may fix your problem. I believe both support Twitpic and Facebook, among many others.

Comment: This is useful but not a total solution :(